# Proof required to prove that a certain matrix combination is an identity matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Suppose I have a certain matrix equation 1

$$A_{2\times1}=M_{2\times 2}B_{2\times 1}$$

and matrix equation 2

$$Ka_{2\times1}=Mr_{2\times2}Kb_{2\times1}$$

And suppose $A^T\cdot Ka=B^T\cdot Kb=1$

Then, I can write 
$$A^T_{1\times2}=B^T_{1\times 2}\cdot M^T_{2\times2}$$
Then multiplying this to equation 2 I get
$$A^T_{1\times2}\cdot Ka_{2\times 1}=B^T_{1\times2}\cdot M^T_{2\times 2}\cdot Mr_{2\times2}\cdot Kb_{2\times1}=1$$

From here, I need to prove that $M^T_{2\times2}=Mr_{2\times2}^{-1}$

But, since matrix multiplication is not associative, I guess that I can't group $B^T$ and $Kb$ together. So, how do I proceed?
Your help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Matrix multiplication *is* associative!

Comment: @egreg but even in that case, I would get $$M^T_{2\times2}\cdot Mr_{2\times2}=1$$ which doesn't make dimensional sense.